# Rails post create is redirecting to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a category controller in the admin namespace, and have another category controller for the actions which won't modify a category. I'm doing this because I need the admin index and show actions to show drastically different templates in the administrative section of the site compared to the front-facing views. However, Rails by default routes from admin categories new, to non-admin categories create. How can I make new and edit call create and update respectively in the admin categories controller? If anyone has suggestions for a better controller layout, I'd be grateful for some insight to good design practices as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use routes namespaces. It will help you to keep admin's logic isolated

Comment: In my routes.rb I have

namespace :admin do
    resources :categories
end

I've also made sure my form_for is form_for ([:admin, @category]), I've removed the create action from the non-admin controller, and it still just isn't working. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: please copy-paste the create method of your admin's namespace controller

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my problem was very trivial. I should have double checked the URL that my Rails program was loading. I hadn't changed my site's admin page to redirect to admin_categories_path, simply categories_controller. Changing this fixed my issue.